# Зачем при переопределении метода вставляется вызов того же метода из суперкласса

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Почему в Intellij IDEA  при переопределении метода через клавиши Ctrl+O в подклассе автоматом вставляется вызов того же метода из суперкласса:

```
public class Foo() {
   public void foo(){}
}
public class SubFoo extends Foo(){
   public void foo(){  //создан через Ctrl+I                                          
      super.foo(); // сгенерировало автоматически 
   }  
}
```

Какие выгоды от такого решения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите.

Виртуальный метод обычно есть средство для того, чтобы вы могли полностью переписать имплементацию для другого класса. Это — один из краеугольных камней ООП: разные классы имплементируют один метод (реагируют на одно и то же сообщение и т. п.) по-разному.

Однако, часто виртуальные методы и используются как простое средство для повторного использования кода. Это тот случай, когда вы хотите делать то же, что делает ваш родительский класс, и лишь немножко «подправить» это. Такой паттерн стал настолько популярен, что даже IDE «помогают» вам в его имплементации. Если вы допишете код к сгенерированному методу, и не удалите вызов `super.foo()`, то вы как раз получите этот эффект: ваш метод `foo` делает то же, что и отцовский, плюс ещё немного.

Comment: Спасибо, суть понял

Comment: @panzermarin: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Никаких выгод. Никаких плюсов. Никаких минусов. Нужно это или нет - определяешь только ты (также неплохо язык подучить, ага) Так делает шаблон который вшит в эту IDE. Измени его если хочешь.

*вообще, некоторые методы требуют вызова super метода, например onCreate() в Андроиде. Но это нюансы*

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно, не спец., но, думаю, не ошибусь, предположив, что сделано сие для того, чтобы переопределённый метод по умолчанию выполнял код супер-класса.

Comment: @argamidon Люблю такие ответы - "неплохо язык подучить" xD


@ЮрийСпб Так это все понятно. Я хочу знать, в каких случаях полезно или необходимо, чтобы выполнялся код суперметода. Ведь IDEA очень продуманная среда, и раз разработчики установили автоматическую вставку вызова суперметода, то это употребительный прием в программировании. Хотелось бы пару небольших примеров, можно на словах, где это используется.

Comment: @panzermarin например, в андроиде нужно вызывать почти все super call-back методы. Это написано в документации. Скорее всего, это сделано, потому что в супер методах происходит вызов каких-то приватных методов-инициализаторов, регистрация в контексте и т.д.